# There is a problem in installing mysql5.5 to rhel6.5

Tags: mysql, linux, rhel, rhel6

My OS is rhel6.5 and I didn't registered.

```
#######################################################################
[root@localhost mysql55]# rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.5.62-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: MySQL-server-5.5.62-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.62-1.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.62-1.el7.x86_64
###################################################################
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a package that has dependencies. If your machine is not registered to the Red Hat network, it wont be able to pull down the packages from the repositories due to the lack of subscription, and it will fail with that message.

If you are using RHEL for development purposes, you could register for a free Developer subscription at the [Red Hat Developers](https://developers.redhat.com) portal. this would allow you to use the repositories.

If you are trying to use it for production (Red Hat Developers subscription is personal and not for production), then you should buy a subscription to enable the repositories or use [Fedora Server](https://getfedora.org/en/server/) or [CentOS](https://www.centos.org) as an alternative.